# Ordenar array de palabras de forma nativa, sin SORT. Utilizando solo FOR e IF

Tags: ordenamiento

estoy intentando hacer una función que ordene un arreglo de palabras. Lo he logrado pero su funcinalidad no es la que debería. Y les explico por qué al final del código que escribí:

```
function ordenarArray(arr) {     
  let aux = null;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
      if(arr[i].length < arr[j].length){
        aux = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = aux;
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

let arr = ['0-CHACA', '1-AREAR', '2-VOY', '3-SOY', '4-CAMINANDO'];
ordenarArray(arr);

//['2-VOY','3-SOY','1-AREAR','0-CHACA','4-CAMINANDO']
```

Bueno, como se puede ver, los ordena "correctamente" de menor cantidad de letras a mayor cantidad. Pero el problema reside en que necesito que no le cambie el orden. El resultado que espero es: ['0-CHACA','1-AREAR','2-VOY','3-SOY','4-CAMINANDO']. Le agregué los números por delante para que sea más claro el inconveniente.

Answer (score 0):

Corrigiendo un poco tu codigo:

```
var list = ['2-VOY','3-SOY','1-AREAR','0-CHACA','4-CAMINANDO'];
console.log(ordenarArray(list))
```

declaramos la varaible list con los elementos a ordenar ya inicializados.
despues llamamos a la funcion ordenarArray donde le pasamos por parametro el arreglo list.

Despues en la funcion calculamos lo siguiente:

```
function ordenarArray(list) {
for (var j = 0; j < list.length - 1; j++) {
  let aux = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
      if (list[i]> list[i + 1]) {
        aux = list[i + 1];
        list[i + 1] = list[i];
        list[i] = aux;
        }; 
    }; 
}
return list;
}
```

Aplicamos el metodo burbuja donde voy a verificar `if (list[i]> list[i + 1]) {` si el elemento de mi izquierda es mayor a la de mi derecha para que asi haga intercambio siempre y cuando se cumpla la condicion y utilize una auxiliar llamada `aux` que se va a encargar de intercambiar los valores para que se ordenen de mayor a menor.
salida:

```
[ '0-CHACA', '1-AREAR', '2-VOY', '3-SOY', '4-CAMINANDO' ]
```